# Atualizar o indice da linha de uma table html

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, html5

Como faço pra atualizar o índice da linha de uma table html após remove-la ?
Explico melhor tenho uma table que posso adicionar ou excluir itens para adicionar eu uso uma variável auto incremento: `_contaLinha++`:

Adicionar itens na tabela:

```
function Adicionar() {            
    if ($("#select_laudoexameid").val() > 0) { 
        $(".tblCadastro tbody").append(
            "<tr>" +
            "<td><input type='text' name='Laudo[" + _contaLinha + "].ExameID'  id='Laudo_ExameID' Value='" + $(".ExameID").val() + "' style='width:100%;border:none;' readonly='true'; class='tblCadastro_exameid'/></td>" +
            "<td><input type='text' name='Laudo[" + _contaLinha + "].TipoExameID'  id='Laudo_TipoExameID' Value='" + $("#select_laudoexameid option:selected").val() + "' class='tblCadastro_tipoexameid'/></td>" +
            "<td><input type='text' name='ListLaudo[" + _contaLinha + "].Nome'  id='ListLaudo_Nome' Value='" + $("#select_exameid option:selected").text() + "' class='tblCadastro_nome'/></td>" +
            "<td><img src='/Content/Images/excluirFlatRed.png' class='btnExcluir' title='Excluir' class='tblLaudoTipoExame_btnexcluir'/> </td>" +
        "</tr>");
        _contaLinha++;
        $(".btnExcluir").bind("click", Excluir);
    };
};
```

Aqui eu retiro item da tabela:

```
 function Excluir() {                      
    var par = $(this).parent().parent();
    par.remove();
};
```

Quando faço o postback eu envio uma lista com 4 itens assim:

```
Laudo[0].nome
Laudo[1].nome
Laudo[2].nome
Laudo[3].nome
```

O problema é quando eu retiro um item da lista, exemplo retiro o primeito item:

```
Laudo[0].nome //<-----Retiro esse item
Laudo[1].nome
Laudo[2].nome
Laudo[3].nome
```

O modelo (modelo Laudo) deveria ser populado com 3 itens, porém o msmo retorna Null, se eu retirar o item 3, exemplo:

```
Laudo[0].nome
Laudo[1].nome
Laudo[2].nome <-----Retiro esse item
Laudo[3].nome
```

o modelo é populado assim:

```
Laudo[0].nome
Laudo[1].nome
Laudo[3].nome
```

preciso que ele fique assim:

```
Laudo[0].nome
Laudo[1].nome
Laudo[2].nome
```

Comment: Você usa o ASP como backend, certo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defina uma classe única para as linhas que contém os dados. Depois disso, após remover o item, você pode fazer isso:

```
    var contador = 0;
    $( ".classeDaLinha" ).each(function() {
        $(this).find("#Laudo_ExameID").prop("name", "Laudo["+contador+"].ExameID");
        $(this).find("#Laudo_TipoExameID").prop("name", "Laudo["+contador+"].TipoExameID");
        $(this).find("#ListLaudo_Nome").prop("name", "ListLaudo["+contador+"].Nome");
        contador++;
    });
```

O que isso faz é percorrer cada linha da tabela que contém a classe que você definiu, procurando os campos pelo id e setando a propriedade nome usando um contador. A cada remoção que você fizer, o contador é reiniciado e cada campo terá o valor reorganizado, deixando sempre na ordem correta.